# Too many Startup Appplications?

Tags: boot, 22.04, startup-applications

I have two laptops both with Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

On the **older** of the two laptops, when I open Startup Applications the following run on boot-up:
[image][image]

On the **newer** of the two laptops, the following run on boot-up:
[image]

Do I need all those applications running at startup on the older laptop?  Can I uncheck most, or all of them? Are they really necessary?

The newer laptop runs great with nothing checked.

They both pretty much run the same programs.

Please allow me to rephrase the question. Are those applications that are checked to start at boot-up necessary to run Ubuntu? I don't want to uncheck necessary applications that will cause me to not be able to boot back in to Ubuntu.

Thank you in advance

New to Linux and love it.

R.P.

Comment: "Do I need all those applications running at startup on the older laptop? Can I uncheck most, or all of them? Are they really necessary?" 1st and 3rd is asking for opinion. Those are for you to decide. 2nd one: that is what the checkbox is there for.  Is is possible the old one is running a "beta"? I have never seen such a list in startup.... IMO: uncheck them all and see if things start failing ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. Please allow me to rephrase the question. Are those applications that are checked to start at boot-up necessary to run Ubuntu?  I don't want to uncheck necessary applications that will cause me to not be able to boot back in to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Allow me to, first, clear a few misconceptions quoted from your question

> when I open Startup Applications the following run on boot-up

These applications run after user login and not on system boot-up.

> Are those applications that are checked to start at boot-up necessary
> to run Ubuntu?

Again these are user account specific startup applications that are run as userspace applications after user login ... These are also out of the scoop of the boot-up process of Ubuntu as a multi-user OS ... i.e. Ubuntu will boot the same even if that user doesn't exist anymore.

> I don't want to uncheck necessary applications that will cause me to
> not be able to boot back in to Ubuntu.

And again Ubuntu boot is not affected by those userspace applications ... You can verify this by creating a new user and log-in to the new user instead after system boot to see that the majority of those startup applications don't even exist under the new user and yet Ubuntu boot-up process is not affected.

##### What might disabling some of those startup applications affect then?

It will only affect that single user's account login session/userspace experience.

##### Do I need all those applications running at startup on the older laptop?

These startup applications entries could be manually added by you(*the user*) or automatically added by e.g. application you installed ... They might be or might not be essential or even needed for that user's requirements and some of them might even be merely leftovers of some removed applications or some deprecated old user specific configuration needs.

##### Can I uncheck most, or all of them? Are they really necessary?

My advice is to experiment with adding a new user account and logging-in to the new user account after system boot to see whether your user experience is affected or not and compare the startup applications between the new user account and the old one to decide for yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I read Raffa's reply and did exactly what he said:
I created a new user, restarted my laptop with this new user, unchecked all the boxes in Startup Applications, rebooted with this new user, played around with programs and internet and such, and everything seems to work fine.

I then restarted as my regular user name, unchecked all the boxes in Startup Applications, rebooted, and everything seems to work fine.

I did, however, leave two boxes checked:

NVIDIA X Server Settings (Configure NVIDIA X Server Settings)

I believe NVIDIA is my laptop video driver and I didn't want to mess with that.

I also kept checked

Update Notifier (Check for available updates automatically)

I didn't want to mess with that as I do security updates as they come in.

Thank you to all who've helped this new-comer to Linux Ubuntu.

R.P.